# How do I get the access token that was returned through Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

Tags: c#, blazor

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization to call my app registration and log in using my credentials. Everything works fine, but I can't figure out how to access my access token after logging in. I have an extremely simple app.

I followed the instructions here: [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

I crteated the app and it looks pretty much exactly like the one on that page. However, I can't find any information on how to get the Token after logging in.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ciao and welcome to Stack Overflow. Even if your app it's basically euqal to the example provided by MSDN, show us some code and where you want to retrieve Token. Answer may come faster and more accurate. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, I will do this in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the access token you need to inject IAccessTokenProvider and request the access token.

You may try the following, in a razor component...

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider

var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();

if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This lead me to the right answer. The other half of what I was missing was adding scopes to the msal authentication. If anyone else needs help, I found this link that kind of made all the pieces fall into place: [Blazor Client can not get access token after login successfully](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21142)

Comment: The way to thank users in stackoverflow is to up-vote / accept their answers.

Comment: @enet How did you use RequestAccessToken function with that scope, i have the same issue here. My tokenResult has value, but tokenResult.TryGetToken return false.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default application, the token gets added to the HTTP client when the requests are being sent to the back end. This is done in the program.cs where the http client is created:

```
   builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorWasmWithAADAuth.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

    // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
    builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BlazorWasmWithAADAuth.ServerAPI"));
```

if you are trying to get the token for calling another resource you will have to create another http client for that endpoint and add the token by creating a custom authorization message handler.